# Nokogiri: Filling in a default value for empty table cells

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape the cell values from an HTML table. Randomly, some of these cells are empty, and I can't guess which ones with any reliability.

Is there a way to fill a default value in for Nokogiri when it comes across an empty cell?

Thanks for any advice you can provide. Here's my code:

```
def scrape_stats
stats = []

(2002..2012).to_a.each do |year|
  url = "website/#{year}"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

  rows = doc.at_css("body tbody").text.split(" ")

  (rows.count / 25).times do |i| # there are 25 columns per row
    stats << rows.shift(25)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
doc.search('td:empty').each{|n| n.content = 'default value'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would basically involve using the [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#add_child`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-add_child) method (or the shorter version, [`Nokogiri::XML::Node#<<`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-3C-3C)) to add a new child node containing the text you want to add to the empty cell.

See this question for an example:

> [How to add child nodes in NodeSet using Nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300095/how-to-add-child-nodes-in-nodeset-using-nokogiri)